# Can you keep changes made to HTML/CSS with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I keep track of my comic book collection online using a mass amount of tables.
I color the table cells based on which ones I have vs. don't have. 
I'm trying to make my life easier by adding some jQuery to my site that will allow me to simply "click" on the cell to change the color.

What I don't know how to do is make the change PERMANENT. It works fine an dandy (and I'm going to add more functionality to cycle through more colors), but when I refresh the page all the changes made to the page are lost.

Is there a way to make the changes permanent?? Adding a "save" button perhaps? Not sure how to achieve this.

**Simple Example of what I'm doing:**

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('td').click(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#5f0');
    });
});
</script>
```

---

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>#1</td>
<td>Comic Title</td>
<td>Collected Edition</td>
<td>Omnibus</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You could create a function that runs on click and on window.load. But I'd recommend just toggling a class on and off and styling with CSS, not JS.

Comment: This is the time to think about local storage and session storage kind of things.

Comment: ^^ Using local storage you could just save the name of the class to toggle, and if its exists on window.load then toggle it on.

Comment: You can follow my answer for some steps to follow to implement this. BTW i have implemented this in a banking project to personalize the entire page for each user. So it works :D

Comment: @mohamedrias thanks for the input, I've never touched JSON or local storage before so that seems a little complicated for me. I think I will try elclanrs suggestion of a toggle (assuming i can do this with more than one color), and if that doesn't work, I'll start researching local storage. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using localstorage or server side storage.

When the user makes changes to the page, store the css properties with respect to an identifier for that field preferrably ID. In JSON format and stringify it before storing to the localstorage.

When the page refreshes or loads, In the onload event , check the localstorage if it has any data. If it's not null  then retrieve the value using the key. let's say "personalization". Then use JSON.parse() to get the original JSON object.

Now loop through the json object and use the key as ID and the value as the css properties. To apply the changes.

Example:

```
var cssprop = { 'cellId' : { 'color': 'red'}}
```

If the above is the json you have constructed on click of the cells.

```
localStorage.setItem("personalize", JSON.stringify(cssprop));
```

now  on window.onload()

```
$(function() {

// In case you are persisting data in the server, make ajax call to retrieve the data and then store it in localstorage.

  if(localStorage.getItem("personalization") != null) {
     var personalize= localStorage.getItem("personalization");
     var cssprop = JSON.parse(personalize);
     // you can iterage the object

     // use $("#"+keyOfObject).css(// use value of object);
  }
});
```